# Como fixar coluna em tabela de forma acessível?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Eu tenho uma tabela com várias colunas e preciso que a primeira coluna fique fixa **na tabela**. Porém, todas as soluções "prontas" que encontrei resolvem criando duas tabelas, o que é inacessível.

Preciso do resultado exatamente como este plugin http://www.michaelkeck.de/projects/jquery/tinytbl/ faz. Porém, sem criar uma nova estrutura HTML, muito menos que divida o conteúdo em **duas** tabelas, o que torna tudo inacessível.

Também já testei usar position:absolute na primeira coluna, mas aí a altura das linhas não fica igual.

Alguém já teve essa necessidade ou precisou de algo parecido?

A tabela é uma tabela normal:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Aluno</th>
            <th>Aula 1</th>
            <th>Aula 2</th>
            <th>Aula 3</th>
            <th>Aula 4</th>
            <th>Aula 5</th>
            <th>Aula 6</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Fábio Rocha</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pode postar seu código? acho que fica melhor pra entender

Comment: Meu velho, coloque um fiddle pra gente ver: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: É uma tabela normal. Atualizei a pergunta com o código. Só preciso que a PRIMEIRA coluna fique fixa, porque terei em torno de 25 colunas.

Comment: Você pode usar uma DIV (position: absolute) no lugar da tag TH.

Comment: Não posso quebrar a semântica da tabela, @GabrielSantos. Preciso manter o padrão web e a acessibilidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
var posicoes = $('tr > th:first-of-type, tr > td:first-of-type').map(function () {
    return $(this).position()
});
var largura = $('tr > td:first').outerWidth();
$('table').css('margin-left', largura);
$('tr > th:first-of-type, tr > td:first-of-type').each(function (i) {
    this.style.position = 'fixed';
    this.style.left = posicoes[i].left;
    this.style.top = posicoes[i].top;
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/YgxU4/)

Comment: Desta forma a primeira coluna fica com posição fixa na página. Preciso evitar isso.

Comment: @FábioRocha, você escreveu: "preciso que a primeira coluna fique fixa". Pode explicar melhor então o que procura?

Comment: No exemplo deste plugin é possível perceber **exatamente** o resultado que eu preciso: http://www.michaelkeck.de/projects/jquery/tinytbl/. Em "Try it", desmarque todas as opções e clique em "Create".

Comment: @FábioRocha, é isto que você quer? __http://jsfiddle.net/y9S8y/__

Comment: A segunda coluna (Columna) está ficando atrás da coluna fixa. E não dá pra usar position:fixed, porque se rolar na vertical a primeira coluna fica parada. Estou testando em cima do seu código, se der certo, posto aqui.

Comment: Nada, sempre dá algum tipo de quebra no layout... a tabela flutua à esquerda etc.

Comment: @FábioRocha, eu só tinha testado no Chrome, vi depois que o IE e o FF não funcionava. Acho que não vai ser fácil esta... mas e assim está melhor?: __http://jsfiddle.net/UJq6B/__

Comment: Finalmente!!! Mudei algumas coisinhas no JS: http://jsfiddle.net/fabiorochafg/nJSvS/2/

Comment: @FábioRocha, boa! Acho que ainda vai dar algum trabalho a inserir numa página real, mas o efeito funciona bem sem quebrar o codigo da tabela! Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Já coloquei no projeto real, essa versão aí foi só pra te mostrar, hehe. Só está faltando um pequeno detalhe para ficar perfeito, mas este deixa para outra **pergunta**, hehehe. Muito obrigado, cara!

Comment: @FábioRocha, optimo! Se acha que eu ajudei pode marcar a resposta como certa. Fico á espera da outra pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Seria isto?

HTML:

```html
<table width=200 height=200 frameborder=1>
<tr class="fixed">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fixed">
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
.fixed td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

## Aqui está um Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMcv9/)

Comment: Amigo, atualizei a pergunta, acho que agora dá pra entender melhor o meu problema.

Comment: @FábioRocha cara realmente não sei fazer isso, mas tem um esquema de `<colgroup>` que pode ser o que tu queres, dá uma pesquisada sobre ele ^^ - mas pelo q eu vi tem que usar duas `<table>` e nao tem como fazer com uma só